# PycURL support for PROXYTYPE_HTTP_1_0?

Tags: curl, pycurl

libcurl documentation says that option CURLPROXY_HTTP_1_0 has been supported since 7.19.4.

PycURL version (on Debian 6) shows libcurl/7.21.0.

But I can't find the constant PROXYTYPE_HTTP_1_0 (that's how they name these) in there.

Anyone know what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURLPROXY_HTTP_1_0 is just an integer constant defined in curl.h You can take a look at it value and pass it by value to setopt.

`* curl.h *
CURLPROXY_HTTP_1_0 = 1,   /* added in 7.19.4, force to use CONNECT`

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 1)
...
```